# How can $y=x^4 + 1$ have 4 zeros?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring, quartics

According to the fundamental theorem of algebra, any polynomial: $ax^w + bx^v + cx^u \ldots$ has exactly $n$ zeroes, $n$ being the highest power of any term.

How can $y=x^4+1$ have 4 zeroes? There must be something I'm missing. My solving works as follows:

$$0=x^4+1 \\ -1 = x^4 \\ x = \pm \sqrt[4]{-1}$$

Isn't this just two solutions: $x= 0.707106781 + 0.707106781 i$ and $x= -0.707106781 - 0.707106781 i$? Where do the other two come from?

Comment: Hint: treat $x^4$ as $(x^2)^2$.

Comment: Regardless, some of the zeroes could have been repeated.  For example $y=(x-1)^4$ has four zeroes, all of which are $1$.  The fundamental theorem of algebra does not state that the zeroes must all be distinct.

Comment: $\sqrt2+\sqrt2i,\ \sqrt2-\sqrt2i,\ -\sqrt2+\sqrt2i,\ -\sqrt2-\sqrt2i$

Comment: $\pm\sqrt i$ and $\pm\sqrt-i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you in the comments, I've come up with a fully solved relatively elementary answer.

$$0=x^4+1 \\ -1 = (x^2)^2 \\ x^2 = \pm i \\ x=\pm\sqrt{\pm i} \\ or \\x= \pm\sqrt{i}, \pm \sqrt{-i} \\ or \\ x= \sqrt{i}, \sqrt{-i}, -\sqrt{i}, -\sqrt{-i}$$

So the 4 solutions are $\left[ \sqrt{i}, \sqrt{-i}, -\sqrt{i}, -\sqrt{-i} \right]$

Comment: Just something extra, but the square root of $i$ isn't well defined. So assume $\sqrt{i}=a+bi$ and solve for $a,b$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^4+1=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2=(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)$

and solve two quadratic equations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $x=\pm\sqrt{\pm\sqrt{-1}} \Rightarrow x=\pm\sqrt{\pm i}$.
So, you have the two roots of plus-or-minus $i$, which are $\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}i}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Noticing that $x^2 = \pm i$ which means that $x^2 \in \left \{ e^{i\pi/2}, e^{3i\pi/2} \right \}$.  Noticing that $-1 = e^{i\pi}$.  We have that

$$
x \in \left \{ \sqrt{i}, - \sqrt{i}, \sqrt{-i}, - \sqrt{-i} \right \}
$$

which we can write in polar form as

$$
\sqrt{i} \;\; =\;\;   e^{i\pi/4} \\
-\sqrt{i} \;\; =\;\; e^{i\pi} e^{i\pi/4} \;\; =\;\; e^{5i\pi/4} \\
\sqrt{-i} \;\; =\;\; \sqrt{e^{i\pi} e^{i\pi/2}} \;\; =\;\; e^{3i\pi/4} \\
-\sqrt{-i} \;\; =\;\; e^{i\pi} e^{3i\pi/4} \;\; =\;\; e^{7i\pi/4}.
$$